# CSS responsive image not staying square

Tags: css

I have an image where the src is loaded dynamically so I don't know the size of it and I also need to keep it responsive so I've set:

```
.resImg {
  display:block;
  border:5px solid yellow;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is that I need to maintain the image squared while still in percentages but some images are appearing rectangular.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you use a fake image (loading it as background image and then using "cover")?

Comment: kindly provide demo jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat CSS trick:

```css
.resImg {
  display:block;
  border:5px solid yellow;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom:100%;
  background:url(http://lorempizza.com/500/500) scroll no-repeat center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="resImg"></div>
```

How does it work?

If the `padding` is set to a percentage, that percentage is calculated from the width of the element. If you want to make the element as tall as it is wide, set the `padding-bottom`(or `padding-top`) to 100%, and the height will be `100%` of the width.

To address the issue with different sized images, just set the image as a background image, like I did in my example.

[Here's a JSFiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/2m7zdgLy/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this hack :

```
.resImg {
  display:block;
  border:5px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Reference](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/maintain-aspect-ratio-for-html-element-using-only-css-in-a-responsive-design/)

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see a little more of your CSS and your HTML, but have you tried setting `height: auto;` when you set the width to 100%? This will keep the image in it's default aspect ratio as the width grows, however if all your images are not square, you may need to take a different approach to square them off without any distortion.

Jacob's solution above works great if using the images as a background is an option.